# mysql select max & group by

Tags: mysql

[image]

That's my table.

How do that? I tried that and it gives only 1 max exp1 result...

```
   "SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE (product_id=$id AND group=1) OR
 (product_id=$id AND group=1) OR
 (product_id=$id AND group=4) OR
 (product_id=$id AND group=7)
GROUP BY group"
```

Comment: Your example does not match your description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select MAX(exp1) GROUP BY group then INNER JOIN that result with your
table1 to grab other details and then filter product_id with WHERE clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 T1 INNER JOIN
    (SELECT `group`,product_id,MAX(exp1) as max_exp1
     FROM table1 
     WHERE product_id = $id
     AND `group` in (1,4,7)
     GROUP BY `group`,product_id)T2
ON T1.exp1 = T2.max_exp1 
AND T1.`group` = T2.`group` 
AND T1.product_id = T2.product_id
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect that fact that you want the maximum exp1 of that product_id=$id. and that group is in (1,4,7)

Comment: yes its work. i love you. I am sending you flowers.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try a in clause of the pair max(product_id, exp1)

```
select * 
from table1 
where   (product_id, exp1) in (
      select max(product_id), max(exp1) 
      from table1 
      group by `group`
      having group in (1,4,7)
```

If you want only select group and id = $id you can

Comment: thx for your post.  i want only show selected groups and need "product_id=$id" ?

Comment: i want to group "group column" and select max value of exp1 and matching $id to product_id

Comment: i'm sorry. i have update my first msg. Can you look again?

Comment: I have update the answer  filtering the result by having on group

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT my_group
            , MAX(exp1) exp1 
         FROM my_table 
        WHERE product_id = 881 
        GROUP 
           BY my_group
     ) y 
    ON y.my_group = x.my_group 
   AND y.exp1 = x.exp1;
```